# Value of i after loop iteration

Tags: python, function, loops, iteration

Consider the following function:

```
def xyz(x,y):
    z = 0

    for i in range(x):
        z = z + y

    return z
```

a. If x is 3 and y is 4, what will be the values of i for each loop iteration?

b. What will be the value of z at the end of each loop iteration? (What is z after the first iteration? What is z after the second iteration?)

I have the answers:

a. 0,1,2

b. 4,8,12

I know these are super simple questions but I just started this and I don't know how to read functions and stuff.

I would love some explanation on why the answers are what they are.

Comment: Show your effort.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your cousin for some help after class.

Comment: You should look into [Python For Beginners](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/) there are plenty of resources to get your started. a) `range(3)` is defined as returning 0 up to but not including 3 b) each loop adds `4`, hence `4, 8, 12`.

Comment: One thing you can do is `print` `z` during every iteration so you can see what is happening inside the loop. Let the code explain itself through debugging :)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function

Comment: I second adding `print` statements. It's the most basic way to get an idea of what's happening at each step.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement

Comment: Play computer. Write down the initial value of each variable on a piece of paper and walk through the statements in the program and execute them yourself, updating the variables on the paper accordingly.

Comment: I don't think SO is the best site for you to be asking these sorts of questions in that sort of way. Have a look around at other sites like http://www.dreamincode.net and similar which are better suited to the kind of discussion you want to have. SO is structured in a Question|Answer format that is not conducive to the sort of discussion you want to have. Using the right tool for the job at hand is an important part of any process and I don't think SO is the tool you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm trying to explain you this program as simple as possible.

```
def xyz(x,y): #This is a program declaration
    z = 0

    for i in range(x):
        z = z + y

    return z
```

You need to call this program somewhere in Python by `xyz(3,4)`. you can use any int instead of 3 and 4.

After the function call, value of x and y in python would be 3 and 4. So, `range(x)` would be `range(3)` which is `[0,1,2]`. Hence i value changes from 0-2. (0 in first iteration and 2 in last).

`z` value would be incremental, as you are doing addition on `i` and `z` itself.
So, it is like this,

> 1 iteration. z = 0 + 0
>   2 iteration. z = 0 + 1
>   3 iteration. z = 1 + 2

and the function returns 3.

Answer (score 0):

**a. If x is 3 and y is 4, what will be the values of i for each loop iteration?**
  It's easy to test this out with adding print statements inside the loop:

```
def xyz(x,y):
z = 0
for i in range(x):
    print i
    z = z + y
return z
```

Range is a function that takes two parameters, beginnig (included) and end (excluded). If there is only one value, then it is the end and beginning is set to 0 by default. Therefore, if x is 3, the values in loops would be 0, 1, 2. but not 3 as this is excluded in Python 2.x. (In Python 3.x, range is replaced by xrange, and there the last value is included, and then the values are 0, 1, 2, 3.)

**b. What will be the value of z at the end of each loop iteration?**(What is z after the first iteration? What is z after the second iteration?)
  Again, use print statements:

```
def xyz(x,y):
z = 0
for i in range(x):
    z = z + y
    print z
return z
```

The values of z in each loop are 4, 8, 12 respectively.The answers are calculated in the following way:
1st iteration: z is 0 and 4 is added to it. The value of z is now 4, as it is overwritten.
2nd iteration: 4 is added to 4, therefore the end result is 8.
3rd iteration: 8 + 4 = 12.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1a.
if you provide single value to range(). It is treated as stop value.
Therefor range(3) will iterate upto <3 i.e 0 1 2.

1b. because z = z + y therefor at first z = 0 + 4 , z = 4 + 4 and at last it will be z = 8 + 4.